# VLookup values from the last 7 days

Tags: excel

I have an excel email list with a column for 'last email date' and a column for status (active, prospect, inactive), and I'm looking to make a v-lookup list of all the emails that have been emailed in the last 7 days AND have a status of 'prospect'.

So in the following screenshot (assuming todays date of 2021-04-08) I would want to return example5@example.com and example6@example.com.

[image]

This might also be a pivot table solution, I'm still pretty new to excel.

Looking online I've found many ways to sum all values in the last 7 days and such, but very little material on how to list values based on another value. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [This may be useful for getting you started](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-filter-function)  you can use filter and sort to pull it off.

Comment: Added a screen shot for clarity, thanks BigBen!

Comment: Does your version of Excel support the FILTER function?

Comment: It does! Thats the avenue I've been following for the last few minutes. The trouble is currently that I'm filtering by both date and status, and the function isn't handling both. Might be something I'm doing incorrectly though.

Answer (score 0):

Using `FILTER`:

```
=FILTER(A4:A10,(B4:B10="prospect")*(TODAY()-C4:C10<=7))
```

[image]

You can add a third parameter, e.g. "No Emails", which will be returned if no rows match the criteria.